# How to limit PIN attempts in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, security, user-accounts, windows-authentication

I want to limit PIN attempt to only one, so that if somebody entered wrong PIN once, it will get locked for that session and he must have to enter the correct password (which will be relatively longer and much secure). And of course wrong PIN enter count should be automatically reset when I enter the right password.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: PIN attempts are already limited to 4 before you are challenged, and if you get a fifth one incorrect, then you have to restart before trying again. Considering a six character PIN, it would be too long before brute forcing it.

Comment: Even brute force won't work, as AFAIK the PIN is blocked after two failed attempts, which makes a maximum of 8 bad guesses before the PIN is lost. Limiting the number to one will lose the PIN after only 2 bad guesses. In any case, I think that the limit of 4 tries is built-in to Windows.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes** , there are ways to do that.

First of all I would like you to tell you that **GROUP POLICY EDITOR** is only available on ***Windows 10 Pro*** and not on ***Windows 10 Home***.
Your requirement can be fulfilled only by using the *Group Policy Editor*.

- Click on Run and type ***gpedit.msc***.The Local Group Policy Editor window appears.
- On the left pane under ***Computer Configuration***
- expand ***Windows Settings***
- then expand ***Security Settings***
- then expand ***Account Policies***
- Under ***Account Policies*** select ***Account Lockout Policy***.
- On the right pane double click on ***Account Lockout Threshold*** and specify the number of login attempts.
- After that you will be asked to confirm the suggested values of ***Account Lockout Duration*** and ***Reset Account Lockout counter***.The suggested values cannot be changed and the default is 30 minutes.*(You will have to bare with this as this is the Microsoft Default Security Policy Setting.)*
- Next click on OK or Apply to apply the changes made.

(The disadvantage of this Security Policy is that after there has been n-login attempts the user account gets locked out. In spite of the user typing the correct PIN or PASSWORD the account is locked for 30 minutes and can't be accessed before 30 minutes timeout, where as the account is accessible after 30 minutes and there is no problem in this).

Comment: I know about this, but I want to limit PIN attempts only (not password) :/

Comment: @VarunAgw i dont think a lot of people understand the difference, Windows 10 introduced that as a feature, but some people never used it yet. May i ask, why go pin instead of a number password?

Comment: @DeerSpotter, a PIN is faster to open a machine, easier to enter in tablets and [as Microsoft puts it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/keep-secure/hello-why-pin-is-better-than-password), better.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you have Windows Home you can do this too - but you have to install GPEDIT.MSC on your computer first as it is not included in the Home OS.  I found a website that batches it and installs it and it works fine, and then you can do this as well.  The website is:
https://www.itechtics.com/easily-enable-group-policy-editor-gpedit-msc-in-windows-10-home-edition/

1. Download Group Policy Enabler from above link.
2. Right-click gpedit-enabler.bat and select Run as Administrator (important, if you don't do this it won't have the security rights to install)
3. This will start the installation process. The process will take a few minutes to install group policy features. At the end, simple press any key to close the command prompt window.
4. ow go to Run –> gpedit.msc. This should open group policy editor.

Again, this worked for me and I had access to the features as listed above.