# How to disable "Change Pincode" message in Windows login screen?

Tags: windows, windows-11, login-screen

I'm using the Windows PIN code to login to my account. But, every time when I enter the PIN code incorrectly several times, it asks me to change my PIN code. But this process is getting annoying as I then have to remember a new PIN code that a may rarely use, since previous PIN codes cannot be reused. This increases the chance that I will forget the new PIN codes. I don't want to turn off the PIN code login option. I only want to disable this feature of changing the PIN. And permitting me to change the PIN back to a previously remembered one? Is this somehow possible to do?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/questions/1043296/how-to-limit-pin-attempts-in-windows-10 and increase number of attempts before lockout. Or use a temp tattoo to record it.

Answer (score 0):

There is not, to the best of my knowledge and experience, a way to turn off this message. Users may need the message.

Put your PIN in a secure password manager like KeePass which has KeePass Touch for Smart Phones.  This way you can look up your PIN code and enter it properly.

Having the proper PIN will go a long way to reducing messages.

I do this myself and it works fine.